# Unity3D for Google Cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have a VR Scene with a C# Script on the camera that allows the user to Click Once to move and again to stop.

```
    public float speed = 1.0f;
public bool startedMoving = true;
public GameObject myCam;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (startedMoving) {
            transform.position += myCam.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

//      if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            startedMoving = !startedMoving;
        }
    }
```

What I want to know is how I can CLICK & HOLD to move Backwards..?
Thank you!

~ b

Comment: When you click  CLICK & HOLD and it is moving backwards, when does it stop moving backward? When you release it? When you  CLICK & HOLD again? You left that information out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enum` the represent the status of the mouse instead of `startedMoving` or multiple `booleans` that will make everything **easier** to implement. The comment in the code **describes** how it works.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickAndHeld : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myCam;
    CLICK_MODE clickMode = CLICK_MODE.NO_CLICK;
    MOVE_DIRECTION moveDir = MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE;

    public float speed = 1.0f;


    //If down for 0.5 secods the it is considered Click and Hold instead of Click
    float clickHoldDetectTime = 0.5f;
    float clickCounter = 0; //Dont not change

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(mover());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {

            //If in NO_CLICK, set to CLICKED
            if (clickMode == CLICK_MODE.NO_CLICK)
            {
                //Change the mode to CLICKED
                clickMode = CLICK_MODE.CLICKED;
            }

            //If in CLICKED mode, start counting to clickHoldDetectTime
            if (clickMode == CLICK_MODE.CLICKED)
            {
                clickCounter += Time.deltaTime; //Increment counter

                //Check if we have reached the clickHoldDetectTime time
                if (clickCounter > clickHoldDetectTime)
                {
                    //Reset Counter
                    clickCounter = 0;

                    //Change the mode to CLICK_AND_HELD
                    clickMode = CLICK_MODE.CLICK_AND_HELD;
                }
            }

            //If STILL down and the the current mode is CLICK_AND_HELD then do clickedAndHeldDown stuff
            if (clickMode == CLICK_MODE.CLICK_AND_HELD)
            {
                clickedAndHeldDown();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //If released and the current mode is CLICKED then do clicked stuff
            if (clickMode == CLICK_MODE.CLICKED)
            {
                clicked();
            }

            //If released and the current mode is CLICK_AND_HELD, change to RELEASED then do relased stuff
            if (clickMode == CLICK_MODE.CLICK_AND_HELD)
            {
                //Change the mode to RELEASED
                clickMode = CLICK_MODE.RELEASED;
                mouseReleasedAfterBeingHeld();
            }


            //Reset each time mouse button is released
            reset();
        }

    }

    IEnumerator mover()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE)
            {

            }

            //Move Forward
            if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.FORWARD)
            {

                transform.position += myCam.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            //Move Backward
            if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.BACKWARD)
            {
                transform.position -= myCam.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void clicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("CLICKED");

        //If Idle, become Forward
        if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE)
        {
            moveDir = MOVE_DIRECTION.FORWARD;
        }

        //If forward, moves become idle
        else if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.FORWARD)
        {
            moveDir = MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE;
        }

         //--------------------------------------------------
        //If backward, moves become idle
        else if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.BACKWARD)
        {
            moveDir = MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE;
        }
    }

    private void clickedAndHeldDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("CLICKED AND HELD");

        //If Idle, becomes backward
        if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE)
        {
            moveDir = MOVE_DIRECTION.BACKWARD;
        }
    }


    //Called when released after being RELEASED from CLICKED_HELD
    private void mouseReleasedAfterBeingHeld()
    {
        Debug.Log("RELEASED AFTER CLICKED AND HELD");

        //If backward, move becomes idle
        if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.BACKWARD)
        {
            moveDir = MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------
        //If forward, move becomes idle
        else if (moveDir == MOVE_DIRECTION.FORWARD)
        {
            moveDir = MOVE_DIRECTION.IDLE;
        }
    }

    void reset()
    {
        clickMode = CLICK_MODE.NO_CLICK;
        clickCounter = 0;
    }
}

public enum CLICK_MODE
{
    NO_CLICK, CLICKED, CLICK_AND_HELD, RELEASED
}

public enum MOVE_DIRECTION
{
    IDLE, FORWARD, BACKWARD
}
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Yes Programmer ! This works Better. THANK YOU !

Comment: @Bentoon I don't know when you want the moving backward to **stop**. Can you answer that? I know this answer is accepted but I want to fix it. When you click CLICK & HOLD and it is moving backwards, when does it stop moving backward? When you release it? When you CLICK & HOLD again? You left that information out.

Comment: I want it to stop backward when you release, but more pressing is I need to go Forward & Backward the direction the Cam points in VR... ideas? THANKYOU

Comment: @Bentoon I am patching it now to make it stop going backward when released. One more question. What if it is going forward then you press the backward button what should happen? Also, what if it is going backward and then you press the forward button what should happen? Should it stop for both cases?

Comment: If it stops in both that would be ideal. but I'm more concerned with the direction is forward/Back in the direction th user is facing. Not word co ord:  myCam.tranform.forward /back/ up & down... Does that make sense? Thank you Much! Programmer

Comment: @Bentoon. Yes. I just fixed the problems except for the camera problems because I don't understand what you are saying about the camera . I am confused on the camera stuff. What's going on? Its not going in the direction you want?

Comment: @Bentoon The gameobject I attached the script to is moving towards the direction the camera is facing or backwards. I did not try it with VR. I tried it in the editor. You can explain if it is doing something different in VR.

Comment: @ Programmer Thank you! My fault, The Cardboard Prefab I am using has the camera head inside of it . When I attached the head as myCam variable it worked perfectly! Thanks So Much for your tenacity !!

Comment: Ok. Glad you got it working. I suggest you change `public GameObject myCam;` to `public Camera myCam;` so that only camera can be attached there and mistake like this wouldn't happen. Also, don't forget that I updated the answer with new code so you may want to update your code with that. Happy Coding!

Comment: @Prorammer : You're a rockstar  ; ) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because you only have one trigger action you're going to have to implement something time based for toggling forward/backwards movement. For example, if you press and release the trigger quickly then forward walk could be toggled, but if you're holding the trigger after N length of time then walk backwards.

He's a practical example to get you starting.

- Pressing and releasing the trigger within 300ms will toggle forward movement
- Pressing and holding the trigger for longer than 300ms will begin backwards movement, releasing the trigger then will stop backwards movement

**This is a theoretical example**

```c#
public float speed = 1.0f;
bool triggerPressed = false;
float triggerHeldTime = 0f;
public bool movingForwards = false;
public bool movingBackwards = false;


void Update ()
{
    // increment hold time if we're still holding trigger
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && triggerPressed)
        triggerHeldTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !triggerPressed)
    {
        // reset everything when trigger initially pressed
        movingForards = false;
        movingBackwards = false;  
        triggerHeldTime = 0f;
        triggerPressed = true;
    }
    else if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0) && triggerPressed)
    {
        // upon trigger release

        triggerPressed = false;

        // if we are not moving backwards, toggle forwards movement
        if(!movingBackwards)
            movingForwards = !movingForwards;

        // always reset backwards movement when we release the trigger
        movingBackwards = false;
        triggerHeldTime = 0f;
    }

    // if the trigger has been held for 300ms then move backwards
    if(triggerHeldTime > 0.3f)
    {
        moveForwards = false;
        moveBackwards = true;
    }


    // actually perform the movement
    if (moveForwards)
    {
        transform.position += myCam.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if(moveBackwards)
    {
        transform.position -= myCam.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You Rob!!!! I modded it and it works in Unity - Will test in Cardboard now...

Comment: It works But I need to go forward & Backward the direction the Cam points in

Comment: Fixed, by applying it to the Head instead of Outer CardboadCam Container

Comment: Glad you got what you needed, nonetheless.